# Difference between index and automatic index

Tags: indexing, nosql, orientdb

In the **Documentation of OrientDB** I find multiple occurrences of statement **Index** and **Automatic Index** but I am unable to differentiate between them.

Is there any difference or just two different terms for the same concept.

Answer (score 1):

When OrientDB docs mention indexes, they just refer to automatic indexes, ie. indexes defined on classes and automatically updated during CRUD operations.

OrientDB also has a legacy feature, that is manual indexes; these indexes are not linked to specific classes and can be manipulated with manual get/put operations